# How to exempt an object from Matlab plot limits calculation

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to add objects to my matlab plots which have defined x limits but span the whole y range. Examples are vertical lines or shaded regions delimited by two x values. I am aware of the option to use the current plot limits like this:

```
plot(1:10)
yl = ylim();
% Use y limits of current plot as y values
patch([ 3 3 5 5 ],[ yl(1) yl(2) yl(2) yl(1) ], 'red');
```

[image]

However I want my users to be able to increase plot y limits afterwards (e.g. to synchronize limits of multiple plots) and also want them to continue profiting from Matlab's automatic setting of plot limits.

This would be archivable if I would use the following code to set the y coordinates of my objects to the largest and smallest possible integers, respectively (`intmax()` and `intmin()` in Matlab) and tell Matlab not to consider that object during calculation of plot limits.

```
plot(1:10)
% Make graphical object which spans the whole possibly y range
p = patch([ 3 3 5 5 ],[ intmin intmax intmax intmin ], 'red');
% Does something like the following function exist?
exemptFromPlotLimitsCalculation(p)
```

Is this possible in Matlab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could plot the `patch` (or `fill`) really large (for example by using `realmax`) and exclude it from rescaling by setting the property `YLimInclude` to *off*

```
patch([3 3 5 5], realmax*[ -1 1 1 -1], 'red', 'YLimInclude', 'off');
```

Comment: Why did I not find this option? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

have a look at [this](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/zoom.html#f37-581205)

In the postActionCallback you can resize your patch

Comment: Thank you. Solution of @nilZ0r is easier in this case but I can use your suggestion nevertheless when adjusting distances between subplots!